# Web page structure

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am currently working on a project and I would like to create group page for the web site like in facebook but I have some question about structuring group page.

Group page has 3 buttons; home.php, settings.php, members.php
I don't wanna pass group id every time when I press button. So, I don't wanna call the links like this; home.php?id=1 or settings.php?id=1. Instead of this, I would like to do like facebook does;

https://www.facebook.com/groups/group_name/members/

I know that group_name part is .php file and by using .htaccess they got rid of the this part, for example: ?group=group_name.

But the question is, how can you show /members/ after a .php file? I hope you understood me. Thank you.

Comment: i think the question is about url rewriting:

Comment: when user clicked members link in group page, I want user to see the link like this; group_name/members

group_name is .php file. But how can you add another php file in url? like this; group_name.php/member.php

Comment: if you search here or google for "url rewriting" you will get lots of hits

Comment: okay dagon, I am gonna check right now. thank you